# Play Developer Console I can't send update to my apps

Tags: android, google-play, updates, production, google-developers-console

I can't send updates to my apps since the new developer console has came.

When I try to press "Edit Production Version" (I use it in Turkish) It gives unexpected error like this screen:

[image: Error screen]

So I can't update my apps. Thanks!

Comment: Which browser you are using? Try clearing your browser cache and try using chrome?

Comment: I'm using chrome and incognito tab for this website. So cache and cookies are clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the same error in Chrome. I tried Firefox i uploaded my app without a problem.